# Problema subiendo Imagen con Django Rest Framework y Xamarin Forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, xamarin.forms, djangorestframework

En el `ViewModel` obtengo la imagen en un `array` de `bytes` y lo agrego a un `MultipartDataContent`.

```
byte[] imageArray = null;
ByteArrayContent imageStream= null;
if (this.file != null)
{
    imageArray = FilesHelper.ReadFully(this.file.GetStream());
    imageStream = new ByteArrayContent(imageArray);
    imageStream.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".Png"
    };

}
this.FechaInicio = this.DateSelected.Year + "-" + this.DateSelected.Month + "-" + this.DateSelected.Day;
this.FechaFin = this.DateSelectedFin.Year + "-" + this.DateSelectedFin.Month + "-" + this.DateSelectedFin.Day;
this.Fecha = DateTime.Today.Year + "-" + DateTime.Today.Month + "-" + DateTime.Today.Day;
Comunicado comunicado = new Comunicado { Fecha_inicio=this.FechaInicio, Fecha_fin= this.FechaFin,
    Contenido = this.Contenido,Tipo= this.TipoSelectedIndex, Asunto= this.Asunto, Fecha_creacion= fecha, Materia=selectedMateria.Id,User_id=1,Path= imageArray };
this.IdColegio = 1;
MainViewModel.GetInstance().ComunicadoCursos = new ComunicadoCursosViewModel(comunicado,this.IdColegio);
Application.Current.MainPage = new ComunicadoCursosPage();
return;
```

Método enviar en el que envió la imagen dentro de la clase Comunicado en el atributo `Path`:

```
private async void Enviar()
{
    var connection = await this.apiService.CheckConnection();
    if (!connection.IsSuccess)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
            "Error",
            connection.Message,
            "Accept");
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
        return;
    }
    Comunicados.Prioridad = PrioridadSelectedIndex + 1;
    var response = await this.apiService.Post<Comunicado>(
        MainViewModel.GetInstance().BaseUrl,
        "/comunicado",
        "/api/v1/listar",
        Comunicados);
    if (!response.IsSuccess)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                "Error",
                response.Message,
                "Accept"
            );
        return;
    }
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                        "Mensaje",
                        "Registrado correctamente",
                        "Accept");
    //MainViewModel.GetInstance().AgendaMedico = new AgendaMedicoViewModel(this.idMedico);
    //Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AgendaMedicoPage());
    return;
}
```

El archivo `Comunicado.cs`:

```
public class Comunicado
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "prioridad")]
    public int Prioridad { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fecha_inicio")]
    public string Fecha_inicio { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fecha_fin")]
    public string Fecha_fin { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "contenido")]
    public string Contenido { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "path")]
    public byte[] Path { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tipo")]
    public int Tipo { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "asunto")]
    public string Asunto { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fecha_creacion")]
    public string Fecha_creacion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_id")]
    public int User_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "materia")]
    public int Materia { get; set; }
}
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Comunicado(models.Model):
    PRIORIDAD_CHOICES = (
        (1, ("Urgente")),
        (2, ("Medio")),
        (3, ("Normal"))
    )
    TIPO_CHOICES = (
        (1, ("Comunicado")),
        (2, ("Evento"))
    )
    prioridad = models.IntegerField(choices=PRIORIDAD_CHOICES, default=1)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField()
    fecha_fin = models.DateField()
    contenido = models.TextField()
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to=comunicado_directory_path, blank=True, null=True,default='comunicado/cancel.png',max_length=5000)
    tipo = models.IntegerField(choices=TIPO_CHOICES, default=1)
    asunto = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha_creacion = models.DateField(default= date.today)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User , null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    materia = models.ForeignKey(Materia , null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    curso = models.ManyToManyField(Curso, through='CursoComunicado')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asunto
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class ListComunicado(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        comunicado = Comunicado.objects.all()
        comunicado_json = ComunicadoSerializer(comunicado, many=True)
        return Response(comunicado_json.data)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            file = request.data['path']
            fecha_inicio = request.data['fecha_inicio']
            fecha_fin = request.data['fecha_fin']
            contenido = request.data['contenido']
            tipo = request.data['tipo']
            asunto = request.data['asunto']
            fecha_creacion = request.data['fecha_creacion']
            materia = request.data['materia']
            user_id = request.data['user_id']
            prioridad = request.data['prioridad']
        except KeyError:
            print("Error")
        rawbytes = bytes(file, 'utf-8')
        print(rawbytes)
        image_bytes = Image.open(io.BytesIO(rawbytes))
        pil_image = Image.open(image_bytes)
        pil_image.verify()
        user = User.objects.get(pk = user_id)
        materia = Materia.objects.get(pk = materia)
        comunicado = Comunicado.objects.create(path = pil_image, prioridad = prioridad, fecha_inicio = fecha_inicio, fecha_fin = fecha_fin,
                                               contenido = contenido, tipo = tipo, asunto = asunto, fecha_creacion = fecha_creacion,
                                               user_id = user, materia = materia)
```

Obtengo el `array` de `bytes` en la variable file.

Archivos `serializers.py`:

```
class ComunicadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    path = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Comunicado
        fields = ('id','prioridad','fecha_inicio','fecha_fin','contenido','path', 'tipo', 'asunto', 'fecha_creacion', 'user_id', 'materia')
```

Estoy intentando convertir el `array` de `bytes` en una imagen. Con la  libreria PIL de Python pero me sale el siguiente error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
        response = get_response(request)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 69, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 483, in dispatch
        response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
        self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in dispatch
        response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\colegioweb\apps\comunicado\views.py", line 44, in post
        image_bytes = Image.open(io.BytesIO(rawbytes))   File "D:\DjangoProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2622, in open
        % (filename if filename else fp)) OSError: cannot identify image file <_io
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private async void AgregarImagen(Mensaje mensaje)
    {
        if (ImageBytes != null)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(ImageBytes);
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/png");
            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "path",
                FileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg"
            };
            string boundary = "---8d0f01e6b3b5dafaaadaada";
            MultipartFormDataContent multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
            multipartContent.Add(fileContent);
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", mensaje.Token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(MainViewModel.GetInstance().BaseUrl +
                "user/api/v1/profile/picture/" + this.User.IdProfile, multipartContent);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                                "Mensaje",
                                "Error",
                                "Aceptar");
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: podrias agregar una explicacion, tu respuesta puede ser mejor, la comunidad te lo agradecera!